# nginx always 404 reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, jenkins, http-status-code-404, nginx-reverse-proxy

Im trying to reverse proxy my jenkins isntance to a subdomain. I used the config from the docs  which looks like this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/

Of course I replace the domain/subdomain with mine. I changed the port of jenkins to 8088. I dont know why, but I'm always getting `Not found 404 error`, when I want to visit the UI of jenkins. The creepy thing is, that any other subdomain reverse proxy I set up is acting the same. So I would say this is a issue with nginx and my config? if I call the subdomain with :8088, I get redirected to jekins UI. But I don't want to enter the port. I just want jenkins.mydomain.com

also my access and error logs dont throw any errors...
I set up a reverse proxy earlier with the same nginx instance for example for gitea. This worked and is currently working properly.

Can anyone help?

Edit:
Conf File:

```
upstream jenkins {
    keepalive 32; # keepalive connections
    server 127.0.0.1:8088; # jenkins ip and port
}
# Required for Jenkins websocket agents
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80; # Listen on port 80 for IPv4 requests

    server_name jenkins.mydomain.de;

    # this is the jenkins web root directory
    # (mentioned in the /etc/default/jenkins file)
    root /var/run/jenkins/war/;

    #access_log      /var/log/nginx/jenkins/access.log;
    #error_log       /var/log/nginx/jenkins/error.log;
    # pass through headers from Jenkins that Nginx considers invalid
    ignore_invalid_headers off;

    location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
        #rewrite all static files into requests to the root
        #E.g /static/12345678/css/something.css will become /css/something.css
        rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
    }

    location /userContent {
        # have nginx handle all the static requests to userContent folder
        #note : This is the $JENKINS_HOME dir
        root /var/lib/jenkins/;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            #this file does not exist, might be a directory or a /**view** url
            rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
            break;
        }
        sendfile on;
    }

    location / {
        sendfile off;
        proxy_pass http://jenkins;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        # Required for Jenkins websocket agents
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        #this is the maximum upload size
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands
        proxy_set_header Connection ""; # Clear for keepalive
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the nginx.conf file so that we can have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: I added it to the question. Its the same as in the docs mentioned in the link. Just changed port nd domain.

Comment: I can see in your proxy_pass statement you are writing name of service and not actual IP and port. Can you please write the port on which your server is running on jenkins in your case. Ex: `proxy_pass localhost:8080`

Comment: sorry, forgot to copy it: upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32; # keepalive connections
  server 127.0.0.1:8088; # jenkins ip and port
}

Comment: I tried to delete all other reverse proxy config files and only symlinked jenkins file. Now it seems to work, but If I use another subdomain for jenkins, it does not take effect...

Comment: Could you please check the users permission?? Sometimes it happened, and you can then add Jenkins user to nginx group.

Comment: Good to hear your previous problem is resolved. You can use another subdoamin nginx.conf file it just has to be with a different name. Let me know if you face any issues in sub domain conf